# Cannot iterate over a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to know how to apply a function over a file of images and save each of them in a separate file. For one image it works successfully, but i cannot apply it to all images.

```
import glob
images = glob.glob('/Desktop/Dataset/Images/*')

for img in images:
    img = np.array(Image.open(img))
    output = 'Desktop/Dataset/Output'
    MyFn(img = img,saveFile = output)
```

Comment: In your first snippet you have `output = 'Desktop...`, so I expect your file to be stored there. In the second snippet you have `saveFile = sv`. What is `sv`?

Comment: What is `sv` in 2nd snippet?

Comment: Try deleting the first `/` in `images = glob.glob('/Desktop/Dataset/Images/*')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not define the `sv` value in your 2nd code snippet.

As the image will be overwrite, try this code:

```py
import glob
images = glob.glob('/Desktop/Dataset/Images/*')

i = 0
for img in images:
    i += 1 #iteration to avoid overwrite
    img = np.array(Image.open(img))
    output = 'Desktop/Dataset/Output'
    MyFn(img = img + str(i),saveFile = output)
```

Comment: @CCZ23 I've just added the code, hope it can work!

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to work as i get`UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U3'), dtype('<U3')) -> dtype('<U3')`!

Comment: @CCZ23 May I ask for the full code?

Comment: @CCZ23 You cannot concatenate an image to a string. You need to replace image_resized with a string data type (i.e the file name).

Comment: Sorry just for clarity, do you mean replace the reshaped line Image.fromarray(Inorm).save(saveFile+'.png') with a string?

Comment: @CCZ23 yes, saveFile need to be a string.

Comment: Got it working thanks, the final line of your code should be `MyFn(img = img ,saveFile = output + str(i))`.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the library os directly with

```py
import os
entries = os.listdir('image/')
```

this will return a list of all the file into your folder

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not setting the `sv` value in your loop. You should set it to a different value at each iteration in order for it to write to different files.

Comment: Thanks very much! I added this but it still doesn't work. Perhaps it is an issue with my function?

Comment: No, you are now using the same output path for all your loop, so the file is being rewritten

Comment: I see! So it is working for all images, but it's just overwriting previously saved images, right? And that needs to be modified in the function or in the for loop i used?

Comment: you can generate a base output file name in your loop, as you already extend it in the function. That way, each call to the function gets a different output file.